# Neither `less` or `less -X` clear screen on exit

Tags: terminal, vim, zsh, tmux, less

Neither `less` or `less -X` clear screen on exit. At the same time, `vim` does....

Env iTerm2, protocol mosh, server Centos + tmux + zsh

iTerm2: report term as `xterm-256color`

tmux: `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'`, no change to alternate-screen

`$TERM` is final set to `screen-256color`

I also tried
    `tput smcup | od -c` and
    `tput rmcup | od -c`

suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/223898/on-quit-less-does-not-clear-its-contents-when-run-in-a-screen-session). It outputs correct answer.

Comment: You disabled `smcup` and `rmcup` in `tmux`, and now they're not working?  That seems to be expected.

Comment: @Mikel I tried deleting `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` in my .tmux.conf. less -X still doesn't clear screen.

Comment: It's also interesting that you say it works in Vim.  Hmm...

Comment: Wait, `less -X` isn't supposed to clear the screen.  What happens without the `-X` option?

Comment: What? Shouldn't `less -X` clear the screen while `less` not? Anyway, I tested `less`, it still didn't work. So basically `less` and `less -X` both don't clear screen in any case I tested.

Comment: No, it's the other way around.  `less` sends `smcup` on startup, and `rmcup` on exit, so after you quit `less`, you are taken back to your shell and can see your shell output but not what you were viewing in `less`.  The `-X` flag disables sending those terminal escapes, so the `less` output is mixed in with your shell output.

Comment: @Mikel thanks. Any idea why `less` still doesn't work here?

Comment: What is the output of `type less`, `echo $LESS` end `echo $LESSOPEN`?

Comment: Does `less -+X somefile` clear the screen?

Comment: @Gilles No, it doesn't.

@jimmij
`type less`: 
`less is an alias for less -R
less is /usr/bin/less`; `$LESS` is `-F -g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4`. `$LESSOPEN` is `| /usr/bin/env lesspipe.sh %s 2>&-`

Comment: I got it! After I clear `$LESS` less somefile will clear screen on exit. I don't know why `less -+X` doesn't work when `$LESS` is set though.. It should looking from man page.. Maybe a bug for `less`

Comment: $LESS is variable with default options for less. You had `-X` there as I suspected, so basically you started `less -X` all the time.

Comment: @jimmij thanks! I thought default means with no arguments.

Comment: do you want to clear screen? i think clearing screen is mostly useless. maybe really you want to restore screen as was before running less + history line for the less run?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is my `$LESS` contains `-X`. Plus `-+X` will set `less` to it's default behavior, which is whatever is specified in `$LESS`, NOT no `-X`. Thus I was running `less` with `-X` all the time. That's why neither cleaned the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. And this thing happened only in iTerm2 on my mac. So i found the solution. You've just to switch off 'Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode' checkbox.

This option is stored in each profile in 'terminal' tab. The screenshot is follow.
[image: Screenshot]