# Want less cmd to clear content on exit in server

Tags: less

Want less cmd to clear content on terminal on exit in server and display back what was there before. I am used to this in my mac and wants the same behavior in the server.

My internet search gives answer to the opposite scenario-- how to retain the content when less exits (`less -X` behavior) and I want the opposite.

I looked at answers at [Neither `less` or `less -X` clear screen on exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156348/neither-less-or-less-x-clear-screen-on-exit)

I am using iTerm2 and in my server
`echo $TERM`  shows xterm-256color
`echo $LESS` shows blank

I use unix but but not at expert level skills. I am specifically seeking what settings I should use so that when I leave less the terminal bash shell content should be back.

Comment: An additional point to those who want to help me solve this.

Comment: An additional point to those who want to help me solve this.  In some servers that I use less exists and clears the screen to show the shell content; but in others, it doesn't. In both cases, $LESS shows blank. My guess is there is something else in the server config/settings that affects this behavior and I don't know enough to investigate this. Our sys admins still don't have an idea why this happens.  For those who know more about this area, your help will be greatly appreciated.